# d3.js Tree link not showing

Tags: d3.js, treeview

Can anybody help me with this code! I can't find out why the links between the nodes aren't showing! since i added the `In()` and `Out()` functions, the tree is no longer interactive!!

```js
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 2px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/m1ii9Y45Gu7EBJRGOLzl?p=preview)

Comment: There is an issue with your json, you have mutltiple objects with the 'nane' key.

Comment: it is supposed to have multiple objects with the "name" key..

Comment: hehe i mean that there are key with values "nane" instead of "name"...Ill try to figure out whats the issue with the tree :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your code. Here's the fixed version:

https://plnkr.co/edit/bB7Lrd1NbN7BaXNa

The essential change is that you have a radial chart and links thus have to be created using radial coordinates (radius, angle):

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });
```

Functional variable diagonal above then works with this call:

```
link.enter().append('path')
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    return diagonal(
      {source:{y:d.source.y, x:d.source.x},
        target:{y:d.target.y,x:d.target.x}
      });
    });
```

You probably want to have links not filled so I've changed that CSS property (in style.css) as well:

```
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Finally, functions In and Out work but you were comparing d.children to a null value not if children property is not existing (and is thus null, undefined). After this change your click function works:

```
//create a window on hover
function In(d) {
  if (d.children == null){
  ...
```

ADDED: your data.json had issues as mentioned by others - JSON structure requires same named variables/properties or it just wouldn't be parsed well using a code.

BTW you should really start implementing new charts using D3.js version 6 or newer. Only few of us who are developing with D3.js from its first versions will be able to support code of version 3 while we are now starting from version 6 or upgrading older scripts to it.